# Read value of previously assigned function to onclick event by javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

I have this code:

```
document.getElementById(myid).onclick = function() {
    HandleGPIO(val1, val2);
};

if (console) {
    console.log(document.getElementById(myid).getAttribute('onclick'));
}
```

And I would like to see how function HandleGPIO() was assigned.

how to debug it? getAttribute does not work here and returns null only

Comment: `onclick` is not an attribute, use `console.log(document.getElementById(myid).onclick)`

Comment: i was thinking the same direction, so how to see what value onclick has?

Comment: `document.getElementById(myid).onclick` should return the anonymous function reference

Answer (score 0):

This will return the content of `onclick`:

```
console.log(document.getElementById(myid).onclick.toString());
```

We can check the values passed to the function by making the function return them. We use an argument to separate the debugging logic from the normal execution logic:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr_inputs.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        document.getElementById(arr_inputs[i]).onclick = function(debug) {

            if(debug === true) {
                return [arr_inputs[i], 0];
            }
            else {
                HandleGPIO(arr_inputs[i],0);
            }
        };
    })(i);
}
```

Then we simply call the function with the argument set to true:

```
console.log(document.getElementById(myid).onclick(true));
```

This will return an array containing the values passed to this instance of the function.

Comment: thanks, this is half way for me. output looks like this: `function () { HandleGPIO(arr_inputs[i],0); }` so it somehow does not show first variable value

Comment: You'll have to be more descriptive about what else you need. Because the way I understand "how function was assigned", that seems unlikely to be possible. Or do you mean the value of `arr_inputs[i]` at the moment it is assigned ?

Comment: OK, sorry. I'll try. I am filling dynamically onclick events: `for (var i = 0; i < arr_inputs.length; i++) {
  (function(i) { document.getElementById(arr_inputs[i]).onclick = function() { HandleGPIO(arr_inputs[i],0); }; ` after it has been done, i'd like to debug if values were properly assigned to onclick event and the function. is my question clear now?

Comment: I think I understand and might have a solution.

Comment: You might need to approve the edit though for this to make sense. I also forgot to add an `i` in the function while editing.

Comment: Great stuff spenibus, many thanks! included that into my code and it is working like a charm. I don't know why javascript programers dont include such basic things in their code. but we have forums, fortunately :) OUTPUT is now `["5", 0]`